# Social Media Sharing Application

Tags: facebook, instagram-api, sttwitterapi

I am new in using social media api's. This question is not about the code, if there is a code it will be great otherwise I just need an idea or a way if it's even possible.

I am trying to work on a web-application using asp.net core and razor pages where a user can upload a picture or write a status or link and through one click they can share to the social media platforms almost on every channel wherever they want.

Till now what I can only research about facebook and came to conclusion that you need an `app_id` and `app_secret` key but how can you make an application that will be used by other users and as I know till now, you can't have `app_id` or `app_secret` key of other users.

Is there any way to do that? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The users don’t need their own app id and secret. They would log in to your app, and grant it permissions to perform certain tasks via API in their name. But for Facebook you can forget about it right away again, because Facebook does not allow posting to user profiles using the API any more, at most you can present users with a dialog to share a link - they would have to type their message to go along with it and submit it manually there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @04FS. Can you refer me some tutorials about these api's?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is explicitly considered off-topic here. Start with the API documentation. You can go research for tutorials yourself, but in that case pay attention to how old they are - lots of things have changed regarding the Facebook APIs over time, so many of them might be outdated.

Comment: @04FS that is the reason why I asked, however thank you for your answer. It does help a lot. I will try to research the latest ones.